# SQL Use LIKE predicate to match empty string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find which SP a column named `column1` is modified by UPDATE query by searching `sys.sql_module`, and since the column is also used in SELECT queries, I think its better to use `'%Column1 =%'` criteria as `LIKE` predicate.

However, system coding standard is not strictly applied, therefore in our database there exists multiple type of codings: `column1=`, `column1    =`,`column1 {tab} =`, `column1 +=`, `column1 {CR}{LF} =`  and etc. Definitely i can't use `%column1%=%` as predicate, but how can I find all (at least most) of them meet my initial predicate?

Assume I accept maximum 10 chars between `column1` and `=` is accepted.

Comment: One idea might be to do multiple replaces (any sort of white space you could expect) and just search for '%column1=%' after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was in the same situation in the past. What my work around was, I removed every space, new line and tab from sql_modules definition column itself then compared with my searched string.

```
Select SP_Def from
 (SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(sm.definition, ' ',''), CHAR(13) +CHAR(10),''),CHAR(9),'') as SP_Def
  FROM sys.sql_modules AS sm ) a
where SP_Def like '%column1=%'
```